# Se puede usar una aplicación de escritorio(winform) como webservice. Asp.net y Winform

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webservice, windows-forms, websocket

espero que me puedan ayudar, mi pregunta es la siguiente:

Necesito saber si es posible que una aplicación de escritorio funcione como webservice.

El objetivo de esto es ejecutar procesos en el cliente, desde el sitio web del servidor, donde se comunican. De tal manera, no tenga la necesidad de estar haciendo publicaciones de webservice en cada computador cliente, sino que pueda instalar una aplicación de escritorio, y este se encargue de recibir comunicación del servidor web.

El proceso que deseo realizar, es hacer impresión directa sin vista previa unos tickets a impresoras térmicas. Cuando hago la prueba en localhost, todo bien, pero cuando publico la aplicación web al servidor, y hace las prueba en un computador cliente esperando imprimir directo, me sale error de imprimir, y es lógico, porque trata de imprimir el ticket en el servidor.

Ya me han dicho que por razones de seguridad, se debe usar el vista previa, pero yo he visto que ha imprimido de forma directa.

Es por eso que deduzco que debe haber algo, o alguna aplicación en el cliente instalado encargado de ejecutar el proceso de imprimir, el cual, tal instrucción la ejecutaría el servidor a petición del cliente.

He escuchado que con websocket es una posibilidad, pero no me ha resultado

Espero que me den alguna idea, o me ayuden, no se si me explique bien.
Saludos

Comment: tengo mi pagina web subida en la nube, pero desde otra parte, abro la pagina web para imprimir(cliente) de forma directa, y veo que no se puede. Y si deseo imprimir desde mi computador(cliente), se me tiene que obligar la aparición de la vista previa.
Pero yo he visto aplicaciones web, que pueden imprimir directo

Answer (score 1):

de poder es posible pero dudo de su estabilidad, te recomiendo usar websocket tal como lo dijiste, pero usa SignalR https://www.asp.net/signalr
que es un websocket de microsoft muy estable y fácil de usar, tu lógica seria enviar notificaciones (push) cada vez que se ejecute la accion.

Comment: ok @Ingwvanegas, sabes si este ejemplo me podría servir y como podría aplicarlo:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yk50AxOvpzM

Comment: Claro podría servir una parte más sin embargo en la página de signalR hay ejemplos descargables que yo mismo e usado para hacer tu cliente o tu servidor web y también para hacer tu cliente o servidor en desktop con winforms o consola, tendrías que usar el servidor web y el cliente winforms (descarga los ejemplos y entenderás, vienen separados por proyecto) y sería todo dedicarle unos minutos tendrás un buen rendimiento

Comment: encontre este  codeproject.com/Articles/804770/… que se ve bueno, pero de casualidad sabes de alguno demo que puedas recomendar ?
@Ingwvanegas

Comment: Por supuesto este es el repositorio oficial https://github.com/SignalR/Samples/tree/master/Samples_2.1.0 puedes abrir estos proyectos con visual studio 2013 en adelante